# Java: Notifying a wait()-ing object

Tags: java

Consider the class

```
class Minute implements Runnable {

  private int min;
  // constructor

  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      min++;
      wait();
    }
  }

}
```

```
class Waker {
  // Unsure
}
```

How do I use the Waker-class to wake up / resume the waiting Minute-object?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Have you read the concurrency tutorials? What are you confused about?

Comment: I have tried calling `notify()` and `notifyAll()` from the instantiated `Waker` object in the main class, no go.

Comment: Why did you think that would work? Again, have you read the concurrency tutorials? You have to call wait() and notify() on the same instance for them to work together. Calling them on two separate instances doesn't do anything.

Comment: Obviously not, hence the reason I'm asking here. I have read some of the documentation, but if we all read the full documentation on every problem, there wouldn't be a need for a forum such as this. We all learn differently, I learn better through dialogue, hence this forum.

Comment: No. Sites like Stack Overflow are for *after* you read the documentation and have a specific technical question- hence the downvotes on your question. Recommended reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wake a thread you need a reference to it directly, like so:

```
Minute min = new Minute();
min.run();

// later
min.notify();
```

How you get that reference into your 'Wake' class code is up to you.

For example, via the constructor:

```
class Waker {
    Minute towake;
    public Waker(Minute m) { towake = m; }
    public void wakeUp { towake.notify(); }
}
```

So the original example becomes:

```
Minute min = new Minute();
min.run();
Waker waker = new Waker(min);

// later
waker.wakeUp();
```

Or you can just call 'notifyAll()' as Batty suggests, but that's very crude.

Comment: That makes sense! I thought I would have to call the `notify()`-function using the exact object that was `wait()`ing, which obviously makes little sense. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helps. I expanded / corrected the answer for you to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

create an object of `Minute` class and call `notifyAll()` on that object.

Comment: I am supposed to wake the Minute-object via a method inside the Waker-class. In the main-method I have both a Minute and Waker-object instantiated. I just can't see how the Waker would be allowed to interfere with the Minute-object.

Comment: when you have object of Minute class, then what interference are you talking about??

Comment: I am supposed to interrupt the Minute-class object using the Waker-class object.

Comment: @krystah You don't wake *objects*, but *threads*. You'll never get it right if you don't understand the concepts.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik is right, first you need to get basics of threading otherwise it could be a nightmare.